# SUM in Sql Server is showing wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running below piece of code

```
SELECT
    SUM(A.score),
    A.id,
    SUM(B.score)
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB B
    ON A.id = B.id
JOIN tableC C
    ON A.id = C.id
GROUP BY
    A.id
```

Shows me wrong sum from both the tables especially for duplicate values of score and id.

Sample Data here

table A

```
id  acore
7   100
7   300.13
7   100
7   300.13
7   300.13
7   100
7   100
7   100
7   100
7   300.13
7   300.13
7   300.13
```

table B

```
id  score
7   300.13
```

table C

```
id
7
8
9
```

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Comment: Add some sample table data, the current result, and the result you want - so we can see the difference!

Comment: On a side Note: I don't see the point of join on tableC?

Comment: if rows in A join to multiple rows in B, they'll be counted multiple times. this is expected behaviour

Comment: Why add tablec but not use it. Each join potentially multiplies the rows so when summing take particular care of joins.

Comment: "wrong sum from both the tables" - What you really asked Sql Server to do  is not sum from both tables, but sum from result set, produced by joining 3 tables.

Comment: @ullas any Idea what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: In order to understand what you are doing wrong we must understand what you are trying to do. You don't tell us what you are expecting in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use sub query to get SUM from tableB:

```
SELECT  A.id,
        SUM(A.amt) as score,
        B.amt
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT B.id, SUM(B.amt) as amt
        FROM tableB B
        GROUP BY b.id) as B 
        ON A.id = B.id
JOIN tableC C
    ON A.id = C.id
GROUP BY
    A.id, B.amt
```

Output:

```
7   2400.78 300.13
```

Comment: Thanx dude this helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give the required result :-

```
select A.id,
(select sum(A.Amt) from tableB B where B.id=A.id) AS TableA_Total,
(select sum(B.Amt) from tableB B where B.id=A.id) AS TableB_Total
from tableA A
group by A.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of the below code. Its working fine in SQL server 2012

```
DECLARE @table_A TABLE (ID int , Score float)
DECLARE @table_B TABLE (ID int , Score float)
DECLARE @table_C TABLE (ID int)

INSERT @table_A
(ID,Score)
VALUES
(7,100),
(7,300.13),
(7,100),
(7,300.13),
(7,300.13),
(7,100),
(7,100),
(7,100),
(7,100),
(7,300.13),
(7,300.13),
(7,300.13)

INSERT @table_B
(ID,Score)
VALUES
(7,300.13)

INSERT @table_C
(ID)
VALUES
(7),(8),(9)

SELECT
    A.ID,
    B.score,
    SUM(A.score) AS [Sum]
FROM @table_A A INNER JOIN @table_B B ON A.id = B.id
     INNER JOIN @table_C C ON A.id = C.id
GROUP BY
    A.id,B.score
```